Easy, accessible hikes in Calanques
We are planning a trip to Marseille and want to experience the Calanques. Normally, we'd do a longer/more rugged hike with the goal of getting down to an isolated spot on the coast. Unfortunately, one of us is recovering from a leg injury, so we're looking for a relatively short (3-5km), flat, and smooth-surfaced hike that still allows us to appreciate the beauty of the Calanques. Ideally, this would be accessible by bus from Marseille. What trails might be suitable?
